# c# Initializing Inner properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, properties, initialization, nested-properties

I have two classes:

```
public class TmpClass
{
    public TmpClass() 
    {
        InnerClass = new InnerClass();
    }

    public InnerClass InnerC { get; set; }
}

public class InnerClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And is it possible to initialize property of InnerClass like this, becouse in this way VS2010 cannot does it.

```
TmpClass a = new TmpClass()
{
    InnerC.Name = "blabla"
}
```

Comment: have you considered using the constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next code snippet:

```
TmpClass a = new TmpClass
{
    InnerC = new InnerClass { Name = "Name" }
};
```

Note, that statement `new TmpClass` will call a constructor by default. Also note: you have wrong constructor declaration. Change `TmpClass` constructor to next code sample, so that it will compile:

```
public TmpClass() 
{
    InnerC = new InnerClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TmpClass a = new TmpClass()
{
    InnerC = new InnerClass
    {
        Name = "blabla"
    }
}
```